# Back button xaml moves in different resolution windows 8.1 xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 app that is using a split view page, and when the app is in a 1366 x 768 the back button and title bar are fine. But when displayed on a resolution of 1920 x 1080 and a 23" monitor the button and title move moves. I've uploaded a screen shot of the button moved on a 23" monitor. I'm not sure how to fix this. I've been using Blend to view the page in different resolution.

[image: Back button moved on a 23" monitor]

Comment: can you post your xaml ?

Comment: The Xaml was to many characters to post so here is a link to a share on my SkyDrive. Thanks and please let me know if there is anything else I can do. http://sdrv.ms/1khfS8v